# Connecting Superset to SQL Server using kerberos and sqlalchemy uri

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, kerberos, apache-superset

How can I connect with SQL server using Kerberos with SQLAlchemy URI within Superset. I am not able to find how to create kerberoised SQLAlchemy URI, which I will feed to Superset to connect with SQL Server. No Luck so far. Anyone have any idea?